# How to remove individuals with fewer than 5 observations from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, count

To clarify the question I'll briefly describe the data.

Each row in the `data.frame` is an observation, and the columns represent variables pertinent to that observation including: what individual was observed, when it was observed, where it was observed, etc. I want to exclude/filter individuals for which there are fewer than 5 observations.

In other words, if there are fewer than 5 rows where individual = x, then I want to remove all rows that contain individual x and reassign the result to a new `data.frame`. I'm aware of some brute force techniques using something like `names == unique(df$individualname)` and then subsetting out those names individually and applying `nrow` to determine whether or not to exclude them...but there has to be a better way. Any help is appreciated, I'm still pretty new to R.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should produce a [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) example.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to include reproducible examples in future questions, but here your response was sufficient without needing one. The actual data is quite unwieldy with over 30 columns and 5,000,000 rows. I see how I could use an example like the one you created to get the point across more clearly in the future, though.

Comment: great ;-). a dummy example is even better (sensu more universal) than a specific one

Comment: The data should be in *this* question, as well as future ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An example using `group_by` and `filter` from `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id=c(rep("a", 2), rep("b", 5), rep("c", 8)),
           foo=runif(15))

> df
id       foo
1   a 0.8717067
2   a 0.9086262
3   b 0.9962453
4   b 0.8980123
5   b 0.1535324
6   b 0.2802848
7   b 0.9366375
8   c 0.8109557
9   c 0.6945285
10  c 0.1012925
11  c 0.6822955
12  c 0.3757085
13  c 0.7348635
14  c 0.3026395
15  c 0.9707223

df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(n()>= 5) %>% ungroup()
Source: local data frame [13 x 2]

id       foo
(fctr)     (dbl)
1       b 0.9962453
2       b 0.8980123
3       b 0.1535324
4       b 0.2802848
5       b 0.9366375
6       c 0.8109557
7       c 0.6945285
8       c 0.1012925
9       c 0.6822955
10      c 0.3757085
11      c 0.7348635
12      c 0.3026395
13      c 0.9707223
```

or with base R:

```
> df[df$id %in% names(which(table(df$id)>=5)), ]
id       foo
3   b 0.9962453
4   b 0.8980123
5   b 0.1535324
6   b 0.2802848
7   b 0.9366375
8   c 0.8109557
9   c 0.6945285
10  c 0.1012925
11  c 0.6822955
12  c 0.3757085
13  c 0.7348635
14  c 0.3026395
15  c 0.9707223
```

Still in base R, using `with` is a more elegant way to do the very same thing:

```
df[with(df, id %in% names(which(table(id)>=5))), ]
```

or:

```
subset(df, with(df, id %in% names(which(table(id)>=5))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do the same thing using the `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(id=sample(1:4,20,replace=TRUE),var=sample(1:100,20))

dt1<-dt[,count:=.N,by=id][(count>=5)]
dt2<-dt[,count:=.N,by=id][(count<5)]

dt1
    id var count
 1:  2  94     5
 2:  2  22     5
 3:  3  64     5
 4:  4  13     6
 5:  4  37     6
 6:  4   2     6
 7:  3  36     5
 8:  3  81     5
 9:  3  90     5
10:  2  17     5
11:  4  72     6
12:  2  57     5
13:  3  67     5
14:  4   9     6
15:  2  60     5
16:  4  34     6


dt2
   id var count
1:  1  26     4
2:  1  31     4
3:  1  44     4
4:  1  54     4
```

Comment: My reputation is still too low to up-vote questions. . . but this worked for me as well. Thank you!

Comment: No worries glad to help out!

Comment: you don't need which in the data.table `i` filter

Answer (score 2):

It can be also with `data.table` using a logical condition with `if` after grouping by 'id'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(.N >=5) .SD, id]
#  id       foo
# 1:  b 0.9962453
# 2:  b 0.8980123
# 3:  b 0.1535324
# 4:  b 0.2802848
# 5:  b 0.9366375
# 6:  c 0.8109557
# 7:  c 0.6945285
# 8:  c 0.1012925
# 9:  c 0.6822955
#10:  c 0.3757085
#11:  c 0.7348635
#12:  c 0.3026395
#13:  c 0.9707223
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), foo = c(0.8717067, 0.9086262, 
0.9962453, 0.8980123, 0.1535324, 0.2802848, 0.9366375, 0.8109557, 
0.6945285, 0.1012925, 0.6822955, 0.3757085, 0.7348635, 0.3026395, 
0.9707223)), .Names = c("id", "foo"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use table. take for instance the data.frame mtcars

```
table(mtcars$cyl)
```

you will see that cyl has 3 values 4 6 8. there are 7 cars with 6 cylinders and if you want to exclude observations with less than 10 then you can exclude the cars with 6 cylinders like that

```
mtcars[!mtcars$cyl%in%names(table(mtcars$cyl)[table(mtcars$cyl)<10]),]
```

this will exclude observations using %in% names and table alone